# Shared VPC and VPC Peering mix

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpc, google-cloud-networking

On Google cloud, I have setup new three projects - dev, research and prod. So, then created an Shared VPC Host and three Service Projects as listed above. Also intend to have separate VPCs for each of these service projects (to add more security layer), hence also intend to use now VPC Peering. But confused here  can we configure both Shared VPCs and VPC Peering on same set of Projects?.  If so then i do not find any links on this and also is this an right thing to do?

Comment: You will have a networking mess unless you know what you are doing. Sometimes the best answer requires understanding the what and why of a question. You mention security, so why do you want to create peering and shared VPCs?

Comment: What do you expose from your projects? API's, webserver, data processing? Trying to understand the context and what do you mean by *more* security.

Comment: When you have a Shared VPC, would it not be redundant to have VPC Peering? (Assuming the goal is to be able to access Dev,research and Prod from backend instance deployed on each network).

Answer (score 10):

Peering and Shared have their own usage. With peering, you are limited to 25 per project and the transitivity isn't possible.

For example, with peering, if you set up a peering between dev and research and between research and prod; dev can't reach the prod (transitivity is forbidden), you have to set up a peering between dev and prod for this. The peering can be interesting when you want to share a VPN or Interconnect endpoint. You perform a peering between the interconnect project and these that want to reuse this connexion.

With share VPC, you don't have the transitivity limitation, all the VM can be in the same VPC, even if they are in different projects.

However, with this config, you break the project strong isolation, your dev project can access to the prod without limitation!

Thereby I recommend you to set up VM network with at least "2 legs": 1 in the shared VPC, the other in a project dedicated VPC. And then to set up the correct firewalls rules on your VPC network for limiting interactions in the shared VPC, but by keeping an unrestricted limitation at project level with the leg in the VPC project.

Answer (score 2):

Peering:
Peering allows internal IP address connectivity across two Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) networks regardless of whether they belong to the same project or the same organization. you are limited to 25 per project and the transitivity isn't possible.

VPC sharing:
Shared VPC allows an organization to connect resources from multiple projects to a common Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network, so that they can communicate with each other securely and efficiently using internal IPs from that network. When you use Shared VPC, you designate a project as a host project and attach one or more other service projects to it. The VPC networks in the host project are called Shared VPC networks.  Eligible resources from service projects can use subnets in the Shared VPC network.